Does there have to exist either a surjection or an injection between two sets?
What I mean is, given two sets $A$ and $B$ (which are infinite or finite) is it true that if there does not exist a function $f:A\to B$ such that $f$ is onto, then must there exist a function $g:A\to B$ such that $g$ is one to one?
To me this feels intuitive since it seems like if no matter how the elements of $A$ are laid out over the elements of $B$ not every element of $B$ is covered, then it should mean that I should be able to take every input of a mapping that maps to a non-unique output and redirect them to a unique element of $B$.
To make what I mean clearer, I'll give an example of a finite set where this is easiest to demonstrate (though this can be demonstrated with infinite sets). Suppose $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{1,2,3,4\}$, then clearly no function from $A$ to $B$ is surjective, because no matter how I map $A$ to $B$, I cannot map to all 4 elements of $B$ with only the 3 elements of $A$; however, I can in fact make an injection, namely $f=\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)\}$.
Another example is with mapping the naturals to its power set. Notice that although there does not exist a surjection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$, there does exist an injection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$:
$$
f(n\in\mathbb{N})=\{n\}.
$$
My question is whether I've overlooked a pair of sets (excluding $A=\emptyset$ or $B=\emptyset$) such that this is not true, and if not how I would prove this. One of my more recent attempts go like this:
Let $A$ and $B$ be sets and let there not exist a $f:A\to B$ such that $f$ is surjective. Also assume a particular $f$ is non-injective; therefore, $\exists x_1,x_2\in A\ni f(x_1)=f(x_2)$. Additionally, since $f$ is non surjective, I know there exists a $y\in B$ such that $\neg \exists x\in A\ni f(x)=y$. From this I know that I can always create a new function
$$
f'(x)=\begin{cases}
f(x) & \text{ if } x\neq x_1 \\
y & \text{ if } x=x_1
\end{cases}
$$
If $A$ where finite I could clearly do this a limited number of times to produce an injection, but I don't quite see how I could use this to generalize this to functions with infinite domains.
Thank you for any help I am extremely new to topology.

This is equivalent to the axiom of choice, see this or this

N.B. this question is not about topology (it's about (elementary) set theory) and I've retagged it accordingly.

@BenSteffan I don't think set theory that requires reasoning about Choice qualifies as elementary.

Thanks for your help!
